# Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got ['Irrigation Engineer', 'Greenhouse Maintenance', 'Greenhouse Manager']

Tags: forms, django-models, model-view-controller, django-views, django-templates

for three days now i have been battling with this error 'Exception Value:
Field 'id' expected a number but got ['Irrigation Engineer', 'Greenhouse Maintenance', 'Greenhouse Manager'].

below is my view

```
def academy(request):
user =  request.user

job = Job.objects.all()
job_list =(jobs.job_title for jobs in job)
personalinfo, created =PersonalInfo.objects.get_or_create(job=job_list)
# personalinfo.job =job_list

credential =Academy_info.objects.filter(user_id =user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    
    form =academyForm(request.POST or None,  request.FILES or None)
    
    if form.is_valid():
        institution =form.cleaned_data.get('institution')
        certificate =form.cleaned_data.get('certificate_obtained')
        dates =form.cleaned_data.get('date_obtained')
        document =form.cleaned_data.get('document')
        
        
        
        # try:
        academy= Academy_info.objects.create(user=user, personal_info =personalinfo, institution = institution, certificate_obtained=certificate,
                    date_obtained =dates, document =document)
            
        # except:
            # messages.error(request, 'Cannot submit credential twice!')
            # return redirect('academy')

    messages.success(request, 'User data saved successful! Click next to proceed')
    return redirect('academy')
    

form = academyForm()

return render(request, 'portal/home/credential.html', {'form':form, 'credentials':credential } )
```

this is my model

```
class PersonalInfo(models.Model):
    first_name =models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    second_name =models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    gender=models.CharField(choices=CHOICE_FIELD, default='Male', max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    marital_status = models.CharField(choices=MARITAL_CHOICES, max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    dob =models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    course_of_study=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    contact_address =models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    passport = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True, blank=True)
    phone= models.CharField(max_length=15, default = +2348123456789, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name +''+ self.second_name +'|'+ self.job.job_title +' | '+ self.course_of_study



class Academy_info(models.Model):
    user =models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank = True)
    institution =models.CharField(choices=ACADEMY_CHOICES, max_length=100, null=True, blank = True)
    certificate_obtained=models.CharField(choices=CERTIFICATE_CHOICES, max_length=100, null=True, blank = True)
    date_obtained =models.DateField(null =True, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='document')
    personal_info =models.OneToOneField(PersonalInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username +' | '+ self.certificate_obtained 



class Job(models.Model):
    job_title = models.CharField(choices=RANK_CHOICES, max_length=100, null=False)
    qualification_needed= models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    closing_date =models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title +' | '+ self.qualification_needed
```

this is the error. i checked my model to see if there is any error but i could not see anythin

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1822, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\adamawa_civil_service_recruitment\portal\views.py", line 62, in academy
    personalinfo, created =PersonalInfo.objects.get_or_create(job=job_list)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 588, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 428, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 974, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 992, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 999, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line
1375, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line
1396, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line
1329, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line
1180, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 120, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1824, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ['Irrigation Engineer', 'Greenhouse Maintenance', 'Greenhouse Manager'].
[22/Oct/2022 13:02:14] "GET /academy/ HTTP/1.1" 500 130740
```

what am i doing wrong. Please someone should help me out. thanks

Comment: I don't use Python but the error seems pretty clear. You're passing an array where an integer is expected, looks like something to do with SQL query prep. The traceback tells you which of your files is causing the problem and even points you to the exact line.

Answer (score 0):

need to be changed in the query set like this ...

```
job = Job.objects.all()
job_list =(jobs for jobs in job)
personalinfo, created =PersonalInfo.objects.get_or_create(job__in=job_list)
```

Comment: I have added the __in keyword as you suggested but the error is still there. ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'irrigation Engineer'. Please help me is there is another alternative. Thanks

Comment: I got stock and cannot proceed with the project. Please help me out

Comment: Plz send me code zip (gdrive link)

Comment: ok this is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cRyQYXTAFPfKQPm8QouWvjDUvqqlM1MS/view?usp=sharing waiting to hear from you. thanks

Comment: plz accept request of file access

Comment: Ok. Link sharing is on now

Comment: sorry for late response i alredy open your project plz tell me your problem and also discribe your problem what you want ??

Comment: I want after a user submitted his academy information, I should see his name in database. For instance a user applied for job, let me see his credentials and his personalinfo in the database. I.e to see who is applying for a particular job at a time, what is his name

Comment: job = Job.objects.all()
job_list =(jobs.job_title for jobs in job)
personalinfo, created =PersonalInfo.objects.get_or_create(job=job_list)
I want this to be in the following model

Comment: academy= Academy_info.objects.create(user=user, personal_info =personalinfo, institution = institution, certificate_obtained=certificate,
                    date_obtained =dates, document =document)